# Objects equinumerous with $3$-ary partitions?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions

There is a concept of the so-called RP-compositions of an integer discussed by K. Q. Ji and H. S. Wilf in [Extreme palindromes](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/website/Extreme%20Palindromes.pdf). They proved the following result too:

**Theorem.** *The number of RP-compositions of $n$ is equal to the number of partitions of $n$
into powers of 2 (“binary partitions”)*.

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there an object similar to RP-compositions which is equinumerous with partitions into powers of $3$ ("$3$-ary partitions")?

Comment: Couldn't one just replace words, viewed in this way as labelled 2-regular graphs, by labelled 3-regular graphs, and require recursive symmetry under the obvious notion of rotating the 3 arms?

Comment: The only minor complication is that RP orders the exceptional element of an odd-length sequence to the middle. The RP3 compositions can be defined recursively as the empty composition, $x+c+c+c$ where $x$ is a positive integer and $c$ is an RP3 composition, or $c+c+c$ as the degenerate case corresponding to $x=0$.